# How to change agentpress listing ribbon color

Tags: genesis

For agentpress pro, There is a button on the right side of feature images shows "Just Listing", "Just Reduced" ribbon. How can i change the ribbon color base on word enter on it? Like Green to Just Listing, Red for "Sold" . ANyone can help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To change the text and background for the Agentpress Pro theme you will need to change the CSS using the following:

```
.listing-text {
   background-color: [your color here];
   color: [your text color here];
}
```

You will have to add this code into a child theme to make sure that it does not get overwritten if you update the theme. If you are not comfortable with creating a child theme you could use the Custom CSS feature of the Jetpack plugin to add the code.